# Compression in google bigquery does not have extension in the generated file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a query in Google Big Query and export the data to Google cloud storage using GZIP compression.

```
JobConfigurationExtract jobExtractConfig = new JobConfigurationExtract().setSourceTable(tableReference).set("results.csv", "CSV")
                    .setDestinationUri("gs://dev-app-uploads/results.zip")
                    .setCompression("GZIP");
```

By using this config i am able to generate a results.zip file successfully in  cloud storage in the configured bucket dev-app-uploads. But the file inside the zip is generated without a .csv extension. When i extract the zip file, i am getting a "results" file and when i manually add the extention .csv and open the file, the contents are there.
But my necessity is to generate the file with .csv extension and zip it and place it in cloud storage.

Please let me know if this is possible or any other better options to upload data from big query using compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`gs://dev-app-uploads/results.zip`

use below

`gs://dev-app-uploads/results.csv.zip`